# Auto Delete Channel in discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

So I'm coding my discord bot to create a new private channel when a member joins and automatically delete the channel after a certain time, say 1 hour. I've made it to create a private channel but can't figure out how to make the channel delete by itself.

If this isn't possible maybe making the channel delete when the user types a specific message(not a command) in the specific channel made for him would be helpful.

Attaching the code for reference. And yes I'm working with Cogs.

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
  async def on_member_join(self,member : discord.Member):
    ChannelName = member.name
    guild = member.guild
    
    channel = await guild.create_text_channel(name = '{}'.format(ChannelName))
    overwrites = channel.overwrites_for(member.guild.default_role)
    overwrites.read_messages, overwrites.send_messages = False, False
    await channel.set_permissions(member.guild.default_role, overwrite=overwrites)
    overwrites = channel.overwrites_for(member)
    overwrites.send_messages, overwrites.read_messages = True, True
    await channel.set_permissions(member, overwrite=overwrites)
    await channel.send ('Success!!')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sleep for an hour with `asyncio.sleep` and use the `TextChannel.delete` method to delete the channel:

```py
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_member_join(self,member : discord.Member):
        ChannelName = member.name
        guild = member.guild
    
        channel = await guild.create_text_channel(name = '{}'.format(ChannelName))
        overwrites = channel.overwrites_for(member.guild.default_role)
        overwrites.read_messages, overwrites.send_messages = False, False
        await channel.set_permissions(member.guild.default_role, overwrite=overwrites)
        overwrites = channel.overwrites_for(member)
        overwrites.send_messages, overwrites.read_messages = True, True
        await channel.set_permissions(member, overwrite=overwrites)
        await channel.send ('Success!!')

        await asyncio.sleep(3600)  # import asyncio
        await channel.delete()
```

Comment: thanks a lot it works. Can you tell me a bit more about asyncio, like what it is and where else can I use it?

Comment: `asyncio` is a library used to write concurrent code using the `async`/`await` syntax, there's a lot of things you can do, it's primarily used in IO bound tasks. You should learn it since you're working with discord.py

Answer (score 1):

The answer of Łukasz Kwieciński works, although you can write it a bit cleaner:

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_member_join(self, member: discord.Member)
    overwrites = {
        ctx.guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False),
        ctx.guild.me: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True),
        ctx.author: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True)
    }
    newChannel = await ctx.guild.create_text_channel(name=f"{ctx.author.display_name}", overwrites=overwrites)
    await asyncio.sleep(3600)
    await newChannel.delete()
```

Have a nice day :)